# Ethereum rainbow chart

Tags: ether, price

Is there an Ethereum rainbow chart showing cryptocurrency cycles, like how there is a Bitcoin rainbow chart?

https://www.blockchaincenter.net/bitcoin-rainbow-chart/

Answer (score 1):

there is a Dodge chart... It has really helped me with investing.  [image: Dodge investing]

Comment: thank you for not answering the question